# Tagging AWS lambda function access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I am trying to use aws cli to tag a lambda function. However, I keep getting the access decided error. I even tried to give the user admin access in IAM, and still it does not work. I guess something else has to be configured somewhere that currently overrides the policy

```
root@fd9f516869e1:~# aws lambda tag-resource --resource $FUNCTION_ARN --tags CURRENT_COMMIT=${CIRCLE_SHA1}

An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the TagResource operation: User: <user ARN> is not authorized to perform: lambda:TagResource
```

The policy attached to the user is

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "<SID>",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "tag:*",
                "lambda:ListTags",
                "lambda:TagResource",
                "lambda:UntagResource",
                "lambda:GetFunction",
                "lambda:UpdateFunctionCode"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "<my lambda ARN>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the documentation for [Lambda API Permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-api-permissions-ref.html) and [AWS Services That Work with IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html)  tag-related calls (`ListTags`, `TagResources`, `UntagResources`) can't be restricted to specific resources.

So access for tagging has to be granted for all Lambda functions. To get it working, you'd need to replace `<my lambda ARN>` in the policy above with `*`.

Comment: So sorry for the late response, but yes, the answer is in the docs of course. Just seemed counter-intuitive in the beginning